# css animationend without animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm in a situation where I need to add a class to an element that *might* cause a CSS3 animation trigger. When the animation has finished I need to continue the execution flow, which can be done by using the `animationend` event of the element.

However the CSS class I'm adding to the element does not always contain an animation and thus the `animationend` is never fired.

Is there a way that I can detect if the added class will trigger an animation so that I can continue the execution flow immediately if this is not the case? Or is there a way to fire the `animationend` without delay if there is no animation?

I've plunked an example of the situation [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p93Sh2?p=preview).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possible solutions are coming to my mind:

1)

As a workaround, set a pseudo-animation to your 'withoutAnimation' class, like:

```
#withAnimation.animate {
    animation: my-animation 0s;
```

}

```
@keyframes my-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    to {
       transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

I guess you could leave the @keyframes empty. It should fire immediately

2) The other: Outsource the callback, thats called after animationend, and let the 'withoutAnimation'-elements call it directly, when they are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I was able to come up with is listening to the animationstart event and check if it triggered after lets say 100ms.

```
function animateElement(id) {

  var elm = document.getElementById(id);
  var animating = false;

  function startHandler() {
    //alert('animation start');
    animating = true;
    elm.removeEventListener('animationstart', startHandler);
  }

  function endHandler() {
    alert('animation end');
    elm.classList.remove('animate');
    elm.removeEventListener('animationend', endHandler);
  }

  elm.addEventListener('animationend', endHandler);
  elm.addEventListener('animationstart', startHandler);

  elm.classList.add('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!animating) {
      alert('no animation');
    }
  }, 100);

}
```

See the following plunker for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/84ExEb2CVBaW5prReQ7h?p=preview